# Base class Undefined WEIRD problem . Need help

Tags: c++

My CGameStateLogo which inherit from CGameState:

CGameState.h

```
#pragma once
#include "GameMain.h"
#include "MyBitmap.h"

class CGameMain;
class CMyBitmap;

class CGameState
{
public:
    CMyBitmap* pbmCurrent;
    CGameMain* pGM;

    int GameStateID;

    virtual void MessageEnter () = 0;
    virtual void MessageUpdate( int iKey ) = 0;
    virtual void MessagePaint( HDC* pDC ) = 0;

    void StateHandler ( int msg, HDC* pDC, int key ); 

public:
    CGameState(void);
    ~CGameState(void);
};
```

After creating and finding, problem comes from here :
I've created 2 classes: CTest and CGameStateLogo

```
    #pragma once
#include "GameState.h"
class CTest:CGameState
{
public:
    CTest(void);
    ~CTest(void);
};

#pragma once
#include "GameState.h"
class CGameStateLogo:CGameState // Bug at this line
{
public:
    CGameStateLogo(void);
    ~CGameStateLogo(void);
};
```

Do VS has problem in naming ?

Thanks for reading this :). Things go WEIRD, I'll update my question later. Sorry for wasting your time .

Comment: What is your exact error message?

Comment: Please post the real code from your editor. Your `#include` filenames doesn't match with the names your provided. Also, does MyBitmap.h incude GameState.h?

Comment: I've updated my question above :)

Comment: These are two lines. Which one is causing the problem? Construction or pushing to a vector?

Comment: Exactly what error message is the compiler giving you?!

Comment: Error 1 error C2504: 'CGameState' : base class undefined d:\my dropbox\work\#today\gdimario\gdimario\gamestatelv1.h 7

Comment: @nXqd: You should put this directly in the question (use the `edit` link). This is important information and this comment is "hidden" by default.

Answer (score 5):

```
pGameStates.push_back( (CGameState*)gameLogo );
```

Since `CGameStateLogo` inherits publically from `CGameState`, the cast is unneccesary. Upcasts are implicit. Simply write

```
pGameStates.push_back( gameLogo );
```

instead.

---

This does probably not solve your compile troubles, though. As to that, you seem to be mixing up `GameState.h` and `CGameState.h`. If that's an actual error in your code, instead of just a copy/paste mistake while writing your question, it could cause this problem.

---

It could also be that there is some circular dependency problem in your headers. You write

```
#include "GameState.h"
```

which *should* define the `GameState` class, *unless* the file has already been included once, but the class definition has not yet been read. This could happen for example in this way:

- Some `.cpp` file includes `GameState.h`.
- `GameState.h` includes `GameMain.h`.
- `GameMain.h` includes `GameStateLogo.h`.
- `GameStateLogo.h` includes `GameState.h`, but this has already been included, so the include is ignored due to `#pragma once`.

Generally, such circular dependencies in header files are a thing to avoid.

Comment: Solution for this issue is, you can use 
#ifndef CGameState
#define CGameState
#endif

Comment: Hmm, I always thought that `#pragma once` was a Microsoftism that was otherwise identical to standard header guards. Apparently not, then.

Answer (score 1):

CGameStateLogo.h is including GameState.h and not CGameState.h.  Is it possible you have a file called GameState.h on the include path (and hence you wouldn't get an error about not being able to include GameState.h)?

Comment: When you create a class name CName, you'll have class name CName but Name.h and Name.cpp